# Make an ID counter for a model in django

Tags: django, model, counter, uniqueidentifier

I want to make a simple ID counter for a model in django. I'd prefer it to start at 1000 instead of 0, so I'm thinking it might be better not to use the [built in id function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields), as I've tried to do here:

```
    def __str__(self):

    return "Job #" + str(id)
```

This (and all other attempts that involve writing a function) just return something like this:

> ```
>   Job #<built-in function id>
> ```

Maybe it's easier to just use a for loop somehow?

Comment: It is `self.id` (or probably safer is `self.pk`)

Comment: A `for` loop...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has a *builtin* function named [**`id`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#id). It calculates a number for a given object that remains fixed throughout the life of the object, and *unique* as well.

In case you thus use `id` in a function, and you do not declare a local variable (or a variable in a more local scope) named `id`. The lookup of the name `id` will result in this function.

But what you here want is the `id` of an object: the `self` object. So you need to use `self.id` instead:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "Job #" + str(self.id)
```

Or cleaner formatting:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "Job #{}".format(self.id)
```

Since it is not guaranteed that a model has an `id` column (since one can define another primary key), it is probably safer to use `.pk` instead:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "Job #{}".format(self.pk)
```

About starting the primary key, there are some questions (with answers) to that, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44422006/auto-increment-non-pk-field-starting-at-1000?rq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130635/how-to-make-a-primary-key-start-from-1000). But the point is, that these are usually auto-increment fields, and the sequence that is used to assign id's is typically database dependent. As a result, there is no straightforward way to solve this problem, since some database systems at startup calculate the maximum of the assigned `id`s and then assign the next one each time. Although some solutions exist, those are typically not *generic*, and another database backend might work differently.